# Function wont reload page in JS

Tags: jquery, json

I am having an issue with my code. Currently, I am pulling items from a JSON database and I have many items displayed on the page. I have a class called showProduct that fires when and item is clicked on the page. This executes a function which narrows the items down to one item and displays its name, image, etc in a DIV.

Further down in my code i am trying to call that same function again (showProduct). I want it to reload the page with the correct item. Is it something to do with the fact that I already called this function once and I am trying to call it again? Below is my code thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  'use strict';

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'path to json',
    success: function(json){

      //check for window hash and display appropriate product category  
      var currentHash = window.location.hash;
      switch(currentHash) 
      {
          case '#tomatoes':
               displayTomatoes(); 
               break;
          default:
               displayAll();
               break;
      }

      //display product category based on click
      $("#tomatoes").click(function(event){
         displayTomatoes(); 
            event.preventDefault();
            window.location.hash = '#tomatoes'; 
      }); 
      $("#displayall").click(function(event){
         displayAll();
      });

      //display tomatoes function 
      function displayTomatoes() {
          var categoryImage = '';

          $.each(json, function (i, item) {
              if (item.itemCommodity == "1120" && item.itemBrandLetter == "C") {
                     categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + item.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + item.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + item.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + item.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + item.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + item.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';
              }
          });



$('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');

              //show individual product function on click
              $(".showProduct").click(function(event){

                 //hide all current products
                 $('#productCategories').hide();

                 //get passed data from other function
                 var clickedItemName = '<h1>' + $(this).data('itemname') + '</h1>';
                 var clickedItemUPC = $(this).data('itemupc');
                 var clickedItemOZ = '<h2>' + $(this).data('itemoz') + '</h2>';
                 var clickedItemDescription = '<p>' + $(this).data('itemdescription') + '</p>';
                 var clickedItemImage = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + $(this).data('itemimage') + '">';
                 var clickedItemGluten = $(this).data('itemgluten');
                 var clickedItemBPA = $(this).data('itembpa');
                 var clickedItemGMO = $(this).data('itemgmo');
                 var clickedItemPageURL = $(this).data('itempageurl');

                 //check if clicked data equals correct item
                 $.each(json, function (i, item) {
                   if (item.itemName === clickedItemName) {
                      clickedItemName 
                   }
                   if (item.itemFullUPC === clickedItemUPC) {
                      clickedItemUPC
                   }
                   if (item.itemPackSize === clickedItemOZ) {
                      clickedItemOZ
                   }
                   if (item.itemDescription === clickedItemDescription) {
                      clickedItemDescription
                   }
                   if (item.imageURL === clickedItemImage) {
                      clickedItemImage
                   }
                   if (item.itemGlutenFree === clickedItemGluten) {
                      clickedItemGluten
                   }
                   if (item.itemBPAFree === clickedItemBPA) {
                      clickedItemBPA
                   }
                   if (item.itemGMOFree === clickedItemGMO) {
                      clickedItemGMO
                   }

                   //assign window hash to each product
                   if (item.itemName === clickedItemPageURL) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      clickedItemPageURL = clickedItemPageURL.replace(/\s/g, '');
                      window.location.hash = clickedItemPageURL; 
                   }
                 });

                   //remove extra characters from UPC
                   var originalUPC = clickedItemUPC;
                   var strippedUPC = '<h2>' + originalUPC.slice(1, -1); + '</h2>'; 

                   //show individual product information
                   $('#productSocialShare').show();
                   $('#individualProduct').show();
                   $('#relatedProducts').show();   

                   //append product information to appropriate DIV
                   $('#productTitle').html(clickedItemName);
                   $('#productUPC').html(strippedUPC);
                   $('#productOZ').html(clickedItemOZ);
                   $('#productDescription').html(clickedItemDescription);
                   $('#productImage').html(clickedItemImage);

                   //check if gluten free is true and show image
                   if (clickedItemGluten == "Y") {
                       clickedItemGluten = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gluten_free_test.jpg">';
                       $('#productGlutenFree').html(clickedItemGluten);
                       $('#productGlutenFree').show();
                   } else { 
                       $('#productGlutenFree').hide();
                   }

                   //check if bpa free is true and show image
                   if (clickedItemBPA == "Y") {
                       clickedItemBPA = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/bpa_free_test.jpg">';
                       $('#productBPAFree').html(clickedItemBPA);
                       $('#productBPAFree').show();
                   } else { 
                       $('#productBPAFree').hide();
                   }

                   //check if gmo free is true and show image
                   if (clickedItemGMO == "Y") {
                       clickedItemGMO = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gmo_test.jpg">';
                       $('#productGMOFree').html(clickedItemGMO);
                       $('#productGMOFree').show();
                   } else { 
                       $('#productGMOFree').hide();
                   }

                });
              closeNav();
          }

          //display all products function 
          function displayAll() {
              var categoryImage = '';

              $.each(json, function (i, item) {

                         categoryImage += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + 'data-itempageurl="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemgmo="' + item.itemGMOFree + '"' + 'data-itembpa="' + item.itemBPAFree + '"' + 'data-itemgluten="' + item.itemGlutenFree + '"' + 'data-itemimage="' + item.imageURL + '"' + 'data-itemname="' + item.itemName + '"' + 'data-itemoz="' + item.itemPackSize + '"' + 'data-itemdescription="' + item.itemDescription + '"' + 'data-itemupc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-hover productImagesCategory" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3>' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';

              });

              $('#imagesCategoryProducts').hide().html(categoryImage).fadeIn('slow');

              //show individual product function on click
              $(".showProduct").click(function(event){

                 //hide all current products
                 $('#productCategories').hide();

                 //get passed data from other function
                 var clickedItemName = '<h1>' + $(this).data('itemname') + '</h1>';
                 var clickedItemUPC = $(this).data('itemupc');
                 var clickedItemOZ = '<h2>' + $(this).data('itemoz') + '</h2>';
                 var clickedItemDescription = '<p>' + $(this).data('itemdescription') + '</p>';
                 var clickedItemImage = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" src="' + $(this).data('itemimage') + '">';
                 var clickedItemGluten = $(this).data('itemgluten');
                 var clickedItemBPA = $(this).data('itembpa');
                 var clickedItemGMO = $(this).data('itemgmo');
                 var clickedItemPageURL = $(this).data('itempageurl');

                 //check if clicked data equals correct item
                 $.each(json, function (i, item) {
                   if (item.itemName === clickedItemName) {
                      clickedItemName 
                   }
                   if (item.itemFullUPC === clickedItemUPC) {
                      clickedItemUPC
                   }
                   if (item.itemPackSize === clickedItemOZ) {
                      clickedItemOZ
                   }
                   if (item.itemDescription === clickedItemDescription) {
                      clickedItemDescription
                   }
                   if (item.imageURL === clickedItemImage) {
                      clickedItemImage
                   }
                   if (item.itemGlutenFree === clickedItemGluten) {
                      clickedItemGluten
                   }
                   if (item.itemBPAFree === clickedItemBPA) {
                      clickedItemBPA
                   }
                   if (item.itemGMOFree === clickedItemGMO) {
                      clickedItemGMO
                   }

                   //assign window hash to each product
                   if (item.itemName === clickedItemPageURL) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      clickedItemPageURL = clickedItemPageURL.replace(/\s/g, '');
                      window.location.hash = clickedItemPageURL; 
                   }
                 });

                   //remove extra characters from UPC
                   var originalUPC = clickedItemUPC;
                   var strippedUPC = '<h2>' + originalUPC.slice(1, -1); + '</h2>'; 

                   //show individual product information
                   $('#productSocialShare').show();
                   $('#individualProduct').show();
                   $('#relatedProducts').show();   

                   //append product information to appropriate DIV
                   $('#productTitle').html(clickedItemName);
                   $('#productUPC').html(strippedUPC);
                   $('#productOZ').html(clickedItemOZ);
                   $('#productDescription').html(clickedItemDescription);
                   $('#productImage').html(clickedItemImage);

                   //check if gluten free is true and show image
                   if (clickedItemGluten == "Y") {
                       clickedItemGluten = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gluten_free_test.jpg">';
                       $('#productGlutenFree').html(clickedItemGluten);
                       $('#productGlutenFree').show();
                   } else { 
                       $('#productGlutenFree').hide();
                   }

                   //check if bpa free is true and show image
                   if (clickedItemBPA == "Y") {
                       clickedItemBPA = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/bpa_free_test.jpg">';
                       $('#productBPAFree').html(clickedItemBPA);
                       $('#productBPAFree').show();
                   } else { 
                       $('#productBPAFree').hide();
                   }

                   //check if gmo free is true and show image
                   if (clickedItemGMO == "Y") {
                       clickedItemGMO = '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded img-margin" src="../images/misc/gmo_test.jpg">';
                       $('#productGMOFree').html(clickedItemGMO);
                       $('#productGMOFree').show();
                   } else { 
                       $('#productGMOFree').hide();
                   } 

                   //show random recipe for each item
                   var url = 'path to json';

                    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

                        var randomRecipe = json[Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length)];

                        randomRecipe += '<div>' + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'">' + '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + randomRecipe.recipeImageCategoryURL + '">' + '</a>' + '<a href="' + randomRecipe.recipePageURL +'">' + '<h3 class="recipeSubCategoryImgCaption">' + randomRecipe.recipeName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';

                        $('#featuredRecipe').append(randomRecipe);

                   });

                   // get similar product for each item
                   var similarProduct = '';

                   $.each(json, function (i, item) {

                        similarProduct += '<div>' + '<a href="#"' + 'class="showProduct"' + '">' + '<img class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block productImage" src="' + item.imageURL + '">' + '<h3 class="recipeSubCategoryImgCaption">' + item.itemName + '</h3>' + '</a>' + '</div>';

                   });

                   $('#productSimilar').html(similarProduct)

                });
              closeNav();
          }

       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. In order for this to work I was able to use window location hash and match it to the item UPC since UPC is already appended to end of hash. That made it possible for me to match the two and show the correct item.